# Highcharts v6.0.0 Annotations Not Working

Tags: highcharts

It looks like Highcharts has added more explicit support for annotations in version 6.0.0 but it doesn't seem to be working. Trying the example right of their website but the described annotations are not appearing on the chart.

Below is the code taken directly from the website:

```
        $(function () {
            console.log('ready ', Highcharts.version);
            Highcharts.chart('container', {
                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                        'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
                },

                title: {
                    text: 'Highcharts Annotations'
                },

                series: [{
                    data: [{y: 29.9, id: 'min'}, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, {
                        y: 216.4,
                        id: 'max'
                    }, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
                }],

                annotations: [{
                    labels: [{
                        point: 'max',
                        text: 'Max'
                    }, {
                        point: 'min',
                        text: 'Min',
                        backgroundColor: 'white'
                    }]
                }]
            });
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 6):

Found the problem.  You need to also require or include a script tag for 'annotations.js' in addition to highcharts.js